# The value is cut off while retrieving the value via regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a universal regular expression that allows to fetch digit values from the following **strings**:

- C1_S2_G11_SH2761
- C1_S1_G789
- C2_S2_SH6917
- C1_S1_G78_G432

> ```
>     public Regex testRegex = new Regex("^C(?<classId>\\d+)_S(?<segmentId>\\d+)_(G|SH)(?<groupShopId>\\d+)(|_|_G|_SH)(?<subGroupShopId>\\d+)$");
> ```

Once i try to fetch the value lets say from string **C2_S2_SH6917** by:

> var match = testRegex.Match(string)
>
> var groupShopIdValue = match.Groups["groupShopId"].Value

it returns me only first three digits after SH **691** but i expect to get all four digits after SH **6917**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```cs
^C(?<classId>\d+)_S(?<segmentId>\d+)_(?:G|SH)(?<groupShopId>\d+)(?:_(?:G?|SH)(?<subGroupShopId>\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IlOyu3/2). The last `_`, `_G` or `_SH` followed with digits is now optional. All unnecessary capturing groups are now non-capturing and do not clutter the regex match object.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `C` - a `C` char
- `(?<classId>\d+)` - Group "classId": one or more digits
- `_S` - a `_S` string
- `(?<segmentId>\d+)`  - Group "segmentId": one or more digits
- `_`  - an underscore
- `(?:G|SH)` - `G` or `SH`
- `(?<groupShopId>\d+)` - Group "groupShopId": one or more digits
- `(?:_(?:G?|SH)(?<subGroupShopId>\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `_(?:G?|SH)` - `_`, then an optional `G` or `SH`
  - `(?<subGroupShopId>\d+)` - Group "subGroupShopId": one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

The 7 is matched as part of the subGroupShopId.

Comment: Thanks for the note @Kristof! How can i update the regex to avoid this splitting?